# Como fazer o texto se ajustar na caixa texto no Android?

Tags: java, android

Como definir um intervalo para o tamanho da fonte para o texto ir ajustando automaticamente na caixa texto do `Android (TextView)` a medida em que vai digitando ou em inserindo.

Existe uma configuração a fazer no `Android studio` ou tem fazer `Script`?

Comment: Como assim? Isso já acontece! O.o

Comment: Você quer diminuir automaticamente o tamanho da fonte de forma a que todo o texto seja visível no *EditText*?

Comment: não, é no `Text`

Comment: Não entendi! Não esqueça de colocar @ramaral para que eu seja notificado dos seus comentários .

Comment: @ramaral no  `TextView`, Ramaral é o seguinte vai ter botões, nesse  tem números e quando você aperta o botão ele vai escrevendo no `TextView` e quando ele completar o campo ele vai diminuindo conforme vai escrevendo até o tamanho definido.

Comment: @ramaral será tem como transformar um `TextView` em uma `EditText`que não apareça o teclado e  aquela barrinha que fica piscando para digitar, é uma ideia, ou algo parecido.

Comment: Veja se é [isto](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView) que procura

Comment: @ramaral acho que isso, é de uso livre ?

Comment: Leia a [licença](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView/blob/master/LICENSE)

Comment: @ramaral gostaria e fazer meu próprio código você poderia me passar se for possível, como que faço para acessar o tamanho do texto e largura da caixa de texto via código

Comment: Isso requer que seja feita outra pergunta. Até porque assim outras pessoas terão possibilidade de responder.

Comment: @ramaral valeu !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Veja essa biblioteca https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview
se eu entendi sua pergunta seria isso que você está procurando.

Comment: sim isso, você não conhece um jeito de fazer isso sem essa biblioteca

Comment: você pode verificar o código da biblioteca e pegar as classes que estam la e adicioná-las diretamente no seu projeto.